# modeltest + simple table mode = parent test failed

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Here simplified version of my model:

```
class TableModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
public:
  TableModel(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QAbstractTableModel(parent) {
  }
  int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override { return 1; }
  int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override { return 2; }
  QVariant data(const QModelIndex &idx, int role) const override { return {}; }
};
```

If I run it in such way (with [Qt model test](https://wiki.qt.io/Model_Test)):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  TableModel tbl_model;
  ModelTest mtest{&tbl_model, nullptr};
```

}

it failed at:

```
// Common error test #1, make sure that a top level index has a parent
// that is a invalid QModelIndex.
QModelIndex topIndex = model->index(0, 0, QModelIndex());
tmp = model->parent(topIndex);
Q_ASSERT(tmp == QModelIndex());

// Common error test #2, make sure that a second level index has a parent
// that is the first level index.
if (model->rowCount(topIndex) > 0) {
    QModelIndex childIndex = model->index(0, 0, topIndex);
    qDebug() << "childIndex: " << childIndex;
    tmp = model->parent(childIndex);
    qDebug() << "tmp: " << tmp;
    qDebug() << "topIndex: " << topIndex;
    Q_ASSERT(tmp == topIndex);//assert failed
}
```

and print:

```
childIndex:  QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,QAbstractTableModel(0x7ffd7e2c05a0))
tmp:  QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0))
topIndex:  QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,QAbstractTableModel(0x7ffd7e2c05a0))
```

I can not understand how should I modify my model to fix this issue?
Looks like the problem in `QAbstractTableModel::parent`,
in other words in Qt code, and `QAbstractTableModel::parent` is private.
Is `QAbstractTableModel` wrong base for modeling of data for `QTableView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QAbstractItemModel::rowCount` and `QAbstractItemModel::columnCount`'s interface allows the view to ask the model for the number of top-level rows/columns as well as asking for the number of children a specific node has. The former is done by passing in an [invalid](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#isValid) `parent`, while the latter is done by passing the specific node's `QModelIndex` as the `parent` parameter.

Your `TableModel::rowCount`'s implementation always returns `1` even when the view passes a valid `parent` (i.e. It is asking for the number of the children of another node). Since this is supposed to be a "Table" model (not a tree model), You should change your `rowCount` and `columnCount` as follows:

```
class TableModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
    // .....
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override {
        if(parent.isValid()) return 0; //no children
        return 1;
    }
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override {
        if(parent.isValid()) return 0; //no children
        return 2;
    }
    //....
}
```

`ModelTest` detects such mistakes by getting the first [child](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index) `QModelIndex` for the root index (0,0) from your model and then asking this child about its [parent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#parent). The reported parent should equal the root index (obviously, this fails in your code since you are not maintaining any of these relationships)...